# Mapping to a Window 10 share over an OpenVPN client connection

Tags: windows, openvpn, network-share

I have a pfsense router with an OpenVPN client connected. I have a Synology NAS on the inside that I can map to over the VPN connection. I am also trying to map to a share on a Windows 10 Pro pc (something that connects just fine from inside the network). When I run the `net use` command to the Windows share from the VPN connection I get a system error 53 (the network path was not found).

If I turn off the Windows 10 Pro pc firewall I can successfully map to the share. So I assume this means there are ports on the Windows firewall that need to be opened to connect over the VPN that don't need to be opened when connecting locally. There are 29 inbound rules in the File and Printer Sharing group. 10 are enabled in my installation.

What ports need to be open in order to map a drive to a Windows 10 Pro share over an OpenVPN client connection?

Comment: I would run a wireshark to see which port block to be sure everything is ok, as it can be because the vpn user come from another IP range too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on the openvpn.net forum [https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=21887]. I had to add the VPN subnet to the scope of the SMB-In firewall rule.

[image]

Not sure why I didn't need to do this to map to the Synology shares. I suppose they aren't using SMB.